# Why is it said that it's difficult to solve for $k$ in $b^k=a$ as a discrete log problem?

Tags: logarithms, discrete-logarithms

I was looking up a tutorial that talked about the finite field and discrete log problem. It's said that solving for $k$ in $b^k=a$ is a problem that is difficult.

The example given was: What power do I raise some number $b$ to, to get $a$?
It then mentions that this could be a one-way function.

What I don't understand is, how is this difficult to solve and why is it a one-way function?

For example, if $b=3$ and $a=99$, I suppose we can solve $k$ by just doing $\log_{3}(99)=4.18265...$, is that right? The only issue I could see here is there is no solution for an integer number since $4.182$ is a real number. And why does it say this is a one-way function since we can use log to get the values back and forth?

Comment: You should understand.... the discrete log is not the same as an ordinary log.  If you fix a modulus (say, a prime $p$), then you want to solve $b^k\equiv a \pmod p$.  Similarly in any finite field.

Comment: The *discrete* logarithm problem concerns doing these exponentiations $\bmod n$ for some positive integer $n$. It's a completely different question.

Comment: @lulu Ohh... Thanks for highlighting this to me! In this case, will there always be an answer when solving $k$ in $b^k\equiv a (modp)$? I believe there will always be an answer for $k$ as long as $p$ is prime? I'm assuming the only way is to brute force and try every single possible value for $k$, right? Also, what does it mean to be a one-way function this in context?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for highlighting this to me! In this case, will there always be an answer when solving $k$ in $b^k\equiv a (modp)$? I believe there will always be an answer for $k$ as long as $p$ is prime? I'm assuming the only way is to brute force and try every single possible value for $k$, right? Also, what does it mean to be a one-way function this in context?

Comment: Reading Wikipedia is (as often) helpful. In particular, one of the first sentences is "Several important algorithms in public-key cryptography, such as ElGamal, base their security on the assumption that the discrete logarithm problem over carefully chosen groups has no efficient solution"... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm

Comment: @xenon  No...you need $b$ to be a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n).  it is not known whether or not one-way functions even exist, but if they do this one seems like an excellent candidate since it is "easy" to compute $b^k\pmod n$ but it seems to be very hard to solve $b^k\equiv a \pmod n$ for $k$.  To stress:  of course, the face that we have not found an easy way to compute the discrete log does not prove that no easy way exists.

Comment: @lulu Thank you!